# Expanding conditional probability for Gibbs sampling with many parameters

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, gibbs

I'm trying to use Gibbs sampling to get the following target distribution:

$$ p(a,b,c \lvert x, z) $$

Where $z = f(x,a,b,c)$ and the rest are independent. I know the following conditional probabilities and can sample from them:

$$ p(a\lvert x, z, b, c), \, p(b\lvert x, z, a, c),  \, p(c\lvert x, z, b, a)$$

My question is how to express the target distribution I need using the ones above.

My attempt was to start with the following:

$$ p(a,b,c \lvert x, z) = \frac{p(a,b,c,x,z)}{p(x,z)} $$

But I'm not sure how to continue (or if it's the right direction)

Answer (score 2):

This is the Hammersley-Clifford(-Besag) theorem:. Here is the version presented [in our book](http://amzn.to/2lQDmJR).

**Definition:** Let $(Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_p) \sim g(y_1,\ldots,y_p)$, where $g^{(i)}$
denotes the marginal distribution of $Y_i$. If $g^{(i)}(y_i)> 0$
for every $i=1, \ldots, p$, implies that $$g(y_1,\ldots,y_p) > 0$$
then $g$ is said to satisfy the *positivity condition.*

**Theorem (Besag, 1974)** Under the above positivity condition, the joint distribution $g$ satisfies
$$
g(y_1,\ldots,y_p) \propto \prod_{j=1}^p \; {g_{\ell_j}(y_{\ell_j}|y_{\ell_1},
\ldots,y_{\ell_{j-1}},y_{\ell_{j+1}}^\prime,\ldots,y_{\ell_p}^\prime) \over
g_{\ell_j}(y_{\ell_j}^\prime|y_{\ell_1},\ldots,y_{\ell_{j-1}},
y_{\ell_{j+1}}^\prime,\ldots,y_{\ell_p}^\prime)}
$$
for every permutation $\ell$ on $\{1,2,\ldots,p\}$ and
every $y' \in \mathfrak Y$.

The conditioning on $(x,z)$ mentioned in the question is irrelevant in that case, since every distribution appearing above is then conditional on $(x,z)$.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, but I'm not sure how to use the theorem for my case yet